# Assign increasing number in a 2D array

Tags: c#

Does anyone know how i can have a 2d Array and add one every time he crosses the for loop?

```
int[,] matrix = new int[10,15];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // Here I am stuck to add one each time the loop passes
        // for example: [0,0] = 0; [0,1]= 1; [0,2] = This should be 2
        // and so it has to go on
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did it do? How was that different from what you wanted? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for good advice on how to present your question.

Answer (score 1):

You define a variable before the first loop and increment it every time:

```
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = value;
            ++value;
        }
    }
```

Note: But please, the next time before you ask a question do some own research as the comment by Peter Duniho suggests.

Comment: or using folmula like: `j+i* matrix.GetLength(1)`

Comment: @Grundy: Correct but perhaps not the way to go for a rookie.

Comment: just yet another variant :-)